# How to generate jacoco report in android project with gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, jacoco

In java project it's very easy,there are two instances in gradle's sample folder.
But when I try to do it in android project,there're a lot of problems.

I can't add

```
{apply plugin: 'java'}
```

and

```
test {
    jacoco{
        excludes = ['org/bla/**']
        includes = ['com/bla/**']
        append = false
    }
}
```

There are some conflicts with android plugin,test is belong to java plugin,so I don't konw how to do. I can do build,checkstyle,pmd,findbugs and test,but jacoco report.

My gradle file is below:

```
//Import android test dependencies
import com.android.build.gradle.api.TestVariant


//Load classpath and define the repository.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}


//Sub project,we can add a lot of sub project here.
project('TVEAndroid')
{

    //Load plugins
    apply plugin: 'android'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
    apply plugin: 'findbugs'
    apply plugin: 'pmd'


    //This is different with the one above,the previous one is just for load classpath,this one is for the real build.
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        }

    //Load dependencies,We will use nesux to hold the repositories in the future,so it will be changed.
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }

    //Jacoco plugin information declaration,but jacoco didn't work here,but it works in the java project with the same configuration. 
    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.6.2.201302030002"
        reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
    }


    //Define android build information
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 18
        buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

             //Set the build path,the root folder
            instrumentTest.setRoot('../TVEAndroidTest')

            //Set the code and resuource path for build
            instrumentTest {
                java { srcDirs = [
                       '../TVEAndroidTest/src/'
                   ] }
              res.srcDirs = ['res']
               assets.srcDirs = [
                    '../TVEAndroidTest/assets'
               ]
                resources.srcDirs = [
                    '../TVEAndroidTest/src'
                ]

            }


            //Define the package name for build
            defaultConfig {
                testPackageName "com.accedo.android.tve.test"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
            }

            // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
            // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
            // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
            // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
            // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
            // by a similar customization.
            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }
    }

    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }

    //PMD task
    task pmd(type: Pmd) {
        ruleSetFiles = files('../config/quality/pmd/pmd-ruleset.xml')
        ruleSets = ["basic", "braces", "strings"]
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    }

    //CheckStyle task
    task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
        configFile file('../config/quality/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')  
        source android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        include '**/*.java'
        exclude '**/gen/**'

        classpath = files( project.configurations.compile.asPath )
    }

    //Findbugs task
    task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {

        excludeFilter file('../config/quality/findbugs/findbugs-filter.xml')
        classes = fileTree('build/classes/debug')
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classpath = files( project.configurations.compile.asPath )

        reports {
            xml {
                destination "build/reports/findbugs/findbugs.xml"
            }
        }

        effort = 'max'
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
        }
    }

}
```

The current problem is "Could not find method jacocoTestReport() ...balabala"

Any advice will be greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

The jacoco plugin is not compatible with Android. To get jacoco reports you need to instrument your classes on your own. To achieve that add this to your gradle build config file :

```
configurations {
   codeCoverage
   codeCoverageAnt
}
dependencies {
   codeCoverage 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.5.10.201208310627:runtime@jar'
   codeCoverageAnt 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.5.10.201208310627'
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'testDefaultFlavorDebug') { /* Name of your test task */
       task.jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.codeCoverage.asPath}=destfile=${project.buildDir.path}/coverage-results/jacoco.exec,sessionid=HSServ,append=false",
            '-Djacoco=true',
            '-Xms128m',
            '-Xmx512m',
            '-XX:MaxPermSize=128m'
    }
}
```

After running your tests you will have a jacoco.exec file in 'build/coverage-results' directory

Comment: Hey, would you mind explaining a little more please?

Comment: Sure, just ask which part you want me to explain

Comment: android-plugin 0.10.+ support jacoco

Comment: Doesn't work for me - getting `Could not find method jvmArgs() for arguments...`. task.name=connectedAndroidTest

Comment: As precised by ben75 the android plugin now supports jacoco since 0.10.+

Answer (score 0):

The only way out for this, I found is to have an Ant task inside of Gradle, to generate Jacoco report. You will need to create an Ant task and then in build.gradle, add this:

```
task coverage(dependsOn: test_task) <<{ /* Name of your test task */
        ant.importBuild 'ant-coverage.xml'
    }
```

The ant file ant-coverage.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project_name" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
<property name="jacoco.dir" value="${basedir}/../../jacoco"/>
<property name="src.dir" value="./src"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="./build"/>
<property name="jacoco.exec.file" value="${build.dir}/coverage-results/jacoco.exec"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes/release/"/>
<property name="result.report.dir" value="${build.dir}/reports"/>

<taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="${jacoco.dir}/lib/jacocoant.jar"/>
</taskdef>

<jacoco:report>
    <executiondata>
        <file file="${jacoco.exec.file}"/>
    </executiondata>
    <structure name="Coverage">
        <classfiles>
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}/"/>
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles>
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}"/>
        </sourcefiles>
    </structure>
    <html destdir="${result.report.dir}"/>
</jacoco:report>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate project to run jacoco tasks such as merge and report.

Example `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacocoTestReport {
  reports {
      xml.enabled true
  }

  group = "Reporting"
  description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."

  additionalSourceDirs = files("$project.rootDir/yourProject/src/main/java")
  additionalClassDirs = files("$project.rootDir/yourProject/build/classes/googleplay/debug/")

  executionData = files("$project.rootDir/yourProject/build/jacoco/yourFlavor/debug/jacoco.exec")
}
```

Make sure to include it in your `settings.gradle`.

Answer (score -2):

At this moment, the java plugin is not compatible with the android plugin that you have to import for the buildscript.

You can still use Jacoco by using ant.java inside the build file

```
ant {
    java { ....}}
```

Comment: Can you please give more details on this solution?